# Algorithms - Shortest Path with Contingent Costs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to solve the following problem :

Given a directed, weighted graph **G = (V,E)**, a source vertex **S**, a destination vertex **T**, and **M**, a subset of **V**, It's required to find the shortest path from **S** to **T**.
A special feature present in **M** is that each vertex in **M**, once 'visited', the weight of a certain edge changes to another value. Both the edge and the new weight will be given for each vertex in **M**.

To help in understanding the problem, [I have drawn an example using mspaint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19xfo.jpg). (sorry for the quality).

In this example, the 'regular' shortest path from **S** to **T** is **1000**.
However, visiting the vertex **C** will reduce the edge weight from **1000** to just **500**, so the shortest path in this case is **200**+**100**+**500**=**800**.

Comment: There is no difference between finding shortest path in

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Finding shortest path in what? I don't understand. Plus, the example I posted shows that there is a difference.

Comment: Sorry, I posted that by accident. Any search in graph is a tree search. Usually you just optimize visited states out. Here, after you visit any state in M you can just consider all the nodes as unvisited, because the graph has changed. So there is no big difference where to search. This is the same as you just transform your graph with M states to equivalent usual graph. It's really easy to do.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Resetting the visited states is not a good idea. [Here is another sample in which your approach will be stuck in an infinite loop](http://i.imgur.com/aVQIV87.jpg).

Comment: Obliviously not. Why should I get infinite loop there? Infinite search could happen only if you have infinite number of states or your modify vertexes change cost differently each time you get there. Any way even in both of this situation, if you use cost search and not depth first search, you won't have infinite loop either. But this description is just equivalent to expanding nodes like here: http://i.imgur.com/7CWrxdG.png

Comment: @AhmedAbdelfattah: I retitled this question, because the original title was a bit vague, if you don't like the new title then of course feel free to change it again

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious I misunderstood you at first, however, your later explanation made it clear.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious: It's not really "the same" as regular shortest path. Building the tree that you are describing incurs an exponential blowup in the size of the graph. If P != NP then my answer shows its unavoidable in some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard and it is clearly in NP. The proof is a relatively straightforward gadget reduction.

This more or less rules out making significant improvements on the trivial, brute force algorithm for this problem. So what exactly are you hoping for when you say "efficient" here?

===

**Proof**

It might be that the problem statement has been unclear somehow so the version OP cares about isn't actually NP-complete. So I'll give some details of the proof.

For technical reasons, usually when we want to show a search problem is NP-hard we actually do it for an associated decision problem which is interreducible to the search problem. The decision problem here is "Given a directed weighted graph as described with associated edge-weight changing data, and a numeric value V, does the shortest path have value at most V?". Clearly, if you have an algorithm for the search problem, you can solve the decision problem easily, and if you have an algorithm for the decision problem, you can use it for the search problem -- you could use binary search essentially to determine the optimal value of V to precision greater than the input numbers, then alter the problem instance by deleting edges and checking if the optimal solution value changed in order to determine if an edge is in the path. So in the sequel I talk about the decision version of the problem.

**The problem is in NP**

First to see that it is in NP, we want to see that "yes" instances of the decision problem are certifiable in polynomial time. The certificate here is simply the shortest path. It is easy to see that the shortest path does not take more bits to describe than the graph itself. It is also easy to calculate the value of any particular path, you just go through the steps of the path and check what the value of the next edge was at that time. So the problem is in NP.

**The problem is NP-hard**

To see that it is NP-hard we reduce from 3SAT to the decision problem. That is the problem of determining the satisfiability of a boolean formula in CNF form in which each clause has at most 3 literals. For a complete definition of 3SAT see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

The reduction which I will describe is a transformation which takes an instance of 3SAT and produces an input to the decision problem, with the property that the 3SAT instance is satisfiable if and only if the shortest path value is less than the specified threshold.

For any given 3SAT formula, the graph which we will produce has the following high-level structure. For each variable, there will be a "cloud" of vertices associated to it which are connected in certain ways, and some of those vertices are in M. The graph is arranged so that the shortest path must pass through each cloud exactly once, passing through the cloud for `x1` first, then the cloud for `x2`, and so on. Then, there is also a (differently arranged) cloud for each clause of the formula. After passing through the last variable's cloud, the path must pass through the clouds of the clauses in succession. Then it reaches the terminal.

The basic idea is that, when going through the cloud for variable `xi`, there are exactly two different possible paths, and the choice represents a commitment to a truth value of `xi`. All of the costs of the edges for the variable clouds are the same, so it doesn't directly affect the path value. But, since some of them are in M, the choice of path there changes what the costs will later in the clause clouds. The clause clouds enforce that if the variables we picked don't satisfy the clause, then we pay a price.

The variable cloud looks like this:

```
        *_*_*_*
       /       \
Entry *         * Exit
       \       /
        *_*_*_*
```

Where, the stars are vertices, and the lines are edges, and all the edges are directed to the right, and the have same cost, we can take it to be zero, or if thats a problem they could all be one, it doesn't really matter. Here I showed 4 vertices on the two paths, but actually the number of vertices will depend on some things, as we will see.

The clause cloud looks like this:

```
        *
       / \
Entry *_*_* Exit
       \ /
        *
```

Where, again all edges are directed to the right.

Each of the 3 central vertices is "labelled" (in our minds) and corresponds to one of the three literals in the clause. All of these edges again have cost 0.

The idea is that when I go through the variable cloud, and pick a value for that variable, if I didn't satisfy the literal of some clause, then the cost of the corresponding edge in the clause cloud should go up. Thus, as long as at least I actually satisfied the clause I have a path from the entry to the exit which costs 0. And if every one of the literals was missed by this assignment, then I have to pay something larger than zero. Maybe, 100 or something, it doesn't really matter.

Going back to the variable cloud now, the variable cloud for `xi` has `2m` vertices in the middle part where `m` is the number of clauses that `xi` appears in. Then, depending whether it appears positively or negatively in the `k`'th such clause, the `k`'th vertex of the top or the bottom path is in `M` and changes the edge in the corresponding clause cloud, to have cost 100 or whatever other fixed value.

The overall graph is made by simply pasting together the variable and clause clouds at their entry - exit nodes in succession. The threshold value is, say, 50.

The point is that, if there is a satisfying assignment to the 3SAT instance, then we can construct from it a path through the graph instance of cost 0, since we never pay anything in the vertex clouds, and we always can pick a path in each clause cloud where the clause was satsified and we don't pay anything there either. If there is no satisfying assignment to the 3SAT instance, then any path must get a clause wrong at some point and then pay at least 100. So if we set the threshold to 50 and make that part of the instance, the reduction is sound.

If the problem statement doesn't actually allow 0 cost edges, we can easily change the solution so that it only has positive cost edges. Because, the total number of edges in any path from start to finish is the same for every path. So if we add 1 to every edge cost, and take the threshold to be 50 + length instead, nothing is changed.

That same trick of adding a fixed value to all of the edges and adjusting the threshold can be used to see that the problem is very strongly inapproximable also, as pointed out by David Eisenstat in comments.

**Running time implications**

If you are economical in how many vertices you assign to each variable cloud, the reduction takes a 3SAT instance with `n` variables (and hence input length `O(n)`) also to a graph instance of `O(n)` vertices, and the graph is sparse. (`100n` vertices should be way more than sufficient.) As a result, if you can give an algorithm for the stated problem with running time less than `2^{o(n)}` on sparse graphs with `n` vertices, it implies a `2^{o(n)}` algorithm for 3SAT which would be a major breakthrough in algorithms, and would disprove the "Exponential Time Hypothesis" of Impagliazzo and Paturi. So you can't really hope for more than a constant-factor-in-the-exponent improvement over the trivial algorithm in this problem.

Comment: Hinting at what the reduction looks like might be beneficial to Ahmed, maybe even describing it in some detail since this isn't CS, and the audience here may have forgotten about how to do reductions.

Comment: This is simply not true. A lot of NP-hard problems have optimizations that can make algorithms run significantly faster. The question is how to solve this efficiently, not what complexity class it's in.

Comment: @G.Bach: I'm not really convinced this isn't a homework problem right now, so I'm a bit reluctant.

Comment: @IVlad: It's true that there are some nontrivial ways to speed up exponential time algorithms. But in common parlance you usually say that "brute force is not efficient" and you seek a solution that takes much less than exponential time and say that is efficient. That's how you can also say things like "there is no efficient way to find a collision in a collision-resistant hash function", even though there are *some* nontrivial things you can do to generically speed this up very slightly. If "efficient" does not mean "asymptotically much better than brute force" then OP should clarify.

Comment: I had no idea that this problem is NP. could you explain your proof?

Comment: @ChrisBeck I couldn't imagine a class where this would be homework, at least not where I studied. In algorithms classes, we got problems in P for which we had to find asymptotically optimal algorithms. In complexity theory classes, we weren't primarily looking to design algorithms, and questions were strictly aiming at "decide which complexity class this problem is in", so algorithms were only involved incidentally when something turned out to be in P.

Comment: I don't think that this is homework either, but I agree with Chris that the problem of deciding whether there exists a path of length less than L is NP-complete (and totally inapproximable to boot, even on acyclic graphs).

Comment: Hmm... it might be that if you look at too many SO questions, they all start to look like homework...